# How to access $(this) and event in defined callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, hammer.js

I'm trying to enable some touch controls through a callback function but I'm having trouble accessing the event as well as $(this) in my callback function. Right now the code looks as follows:

```
$('.img-responsive').each(touchControls);

function touchControls(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var mc = new Hammer(this);
    mc.on("doubletap", function() {
        console.log($(this));
    });
}
```

Where '.img-responsive' is a class of images on my page.

When it tries to call event.preventDefault, I get an error that event.preventDefault is not a function. I thought the event was automatically passed to the variable called? I know when I did a named callback function with .on, event.preventDefault() worked perfectly fine. I assume it's different when I do it with .each, how do I properly access it?

Now, if I remove the event.preventDefault() line, when it logs $(this), I get a function. I was expecting to get individual elements so I could set touch controls for them, but that clearly didn't work. I tried to bind 'this' by:

```
$('.img-responsive').each(touchControls).bind(this);
```

But when I logged $(this), it was still a function and not the element I was expecting.

I'm basically just confused as to how to access $(this) and event within the defined callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is not an event handler so its callback function does not accept an `event` object. The method signature of the `each` callback function looks like this:

> **.each( function )**
>
> **function** 
> Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )
> A function to execute for each matched element.

So you won't have an `event` object to reference but, more importantly, there will be no default event behavior to prevent.

Conversely, [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) does in fact setup event handlers. Its callback function does take an event as its parameter. You can handle your event management within your event handler code, inside the callback function for `.on`.

`this` will refer to your current element as you iterate. But inside your inner callback function there will be a different context (so a different `this`). Simply store a reference to the element in the outer scope:

```
function touchControls() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var mc = new Hammer(this);
    mc.on("doubletap", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($this);
    });
}
```

Comment: In this case, how do I prevent the default behaviour of the doubletap event from zooming in? If I'm not supposed to prevent it here, then where do I access it to prevent it?

Comment: @MichaelYousef Updated my response to address the event managing.

Comment: I guess Hammer changes the context so this points to the function for doubletap? Regardless, your solution worked so thanks.

Comment: @MichaelYousef It's not so much `Hammer` changing the context as it is `on`. From the docs: "*When jQuery calls a handler, the* `this` *keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached*" In your case the handler is bound to `mc`, so that's what `this` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

You have the event being passed in the wrong function.. You need to pass it into the event listener. The first argument of an each loop is the current index of the iteration.

```js
$('.img-responsive').each(touchControls);

function touchControls(eachIndex) {
  var mc = new Hammer(this);
  mc.on("doubletap", function(event) {
    // move preventDefault here and pass the event
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this));
  });
}

function Hammer(el){
  return $(el)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-responsive">img</div>
<div class="img-responsive">img</div>
```